# how do you remove a language version of a sitecore item?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

I think i could not make the question more explicit than what is in the title; on the content editor, you can click on the flag item and add a new language version, but no idea how to remove one

on the versions ribbon, you can remove a version number, but it doesn't seem to allow you to pick a single language of the current version for removal

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Select 'Versions' in a ribbon tag. Switch 'Language' to the language you want to remove version from. Click 'Remove' in the 'Versions' commands group.

[image: Sitecore - remove a language version]

It will remove only the current version from the chosen language - it will NOT remove version from any other language.

Comment: This could really be labeled a lot better couldn't it...

Comment: yes, absolutely!