# Remove Item Version

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1

Reference to Sitecore's [documentations](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/content_authoring/getting_started_with_content_authoring/working_with_items/add_or_remove_a_version_of_an_item) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575128/how-do-you-remove-a-language-version-of-a-sitecore-item) related question, the 'Versions' tab in the Ribbon tag supposed to have the option 'Remove' to remove specific language version of the selected item, I have this option for most of the items, but in below scenario, after adding new language version to item, I can't find 'Remove' option:

**Create Template 'Sample'-> Create Section 'Data' -> Add Field inside (which is item at the end) -> Add new language version of this field -> Here 'Remove' option will not be exist in 'Versions' tab.**

**Note:** I've just added this version by mistake and just want to Undo it (remove this version).

Comment: did you try with an admin user to delete version?

Comment: Yes I'm using the default Admin user

Comment: this is Sitecore behaviour on Template fields, what do you want to achieve? You can see just almost all the fieldds are Shared. I remarked just Title is unversioned field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot remove version of templates, template sections and template fields using Content Editor.

You can use DB Browser application instead. You can open it using `/sitecore/admin/dbbrowser.aspx` url.

You will see `Delete version` button there.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a tool which is already available from Sitecore Marketplace. The tool allows you to remove the different version on items. For example, if you select an item, it will show all the version the item contains and also possible language version.

[image]

Here is the link to the module on marketplace: [Sitecore Version Remover](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/B/Batch_Version_Remover.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the correct rights. It should show remove button like follows:

[image]